# Extract Tabular Data from a PDF and sort it

Tags: pdf

I have a PDF file which has the marklist of certain exam.

I am particularly interested in the first list, but which unfortunately has 2112 entries. And they aren't properly formatted. I need to sort all these entries (based on marks in last 2 columns- sum of marks in Aptitude and Computer), to know what my rank is.

I tried to copy in in MS Word and Excel, but if you try it, you can see it won't help. After pasting it in a plain text file, I tried to format it using regular expressions (in Notepad++), wrote a code in C to properly separate each field by '\t' (so that later I can properly copy them in an Excel sheet), but the inconsistency made me fail (some entries are spawned multiple lines, the "names" do not have fixed no. of fields).

Can someone come up with any idea that will make it possible to copy the first list in PDF to a spreadsheet in tabular form exactly as the original file?

Answer (score 1):

1. For a background about why the ***PDF file format should never, ever be thought of as suitable for hosting extractable, structured data***, see this article:

   - **[Why Updating Dollars for Docs Was So Difficult](http://www.propublica.org/nerds/item/heart-of-nerd-darkness-why-dollars-for-docs-was-so-difficult)**
2. For an amazing open source family of tools that gets better and better from week to week for extracting tabular data from PDFs (unless they are scanned pages) -- ***contradicting point '1.' above***! -- see these links:

   - **[Introducing Tabula: Upload a PDF, get back tabular CSV data. Poof!](https://source.opennews.org/en-US/articles/introducing-tabula/)**
   - **[Tabula-Extractor: A Command Line Interface to Tabula](https://github.com/tabulapdf/tabula-extractor)**
   - **[Tabula source code repository](https://github.com/tabulapdf/tabula)**
   - **[Tabula API (upcoming, not ready yet)](https://github.com/tabulapdf/tabula-api)**

Comment: I found Tabula thanks to your answer, and it works very well for me.

Answer (score 0):

I once was tasked with building a parser which would extract data from a pdf with tabular and non-tabular data in a number of different encodings and with a mix a rtl and ltr text. That project took quite the effort but with a simple *English* table you should be able to dissect the pdf in no time. Look for the PDF specs on adobe.com and if it is that desperate start digging in.

Also you'll first need to use pdftk.exe to uncompress the file.

**A shortcut that me be of aid:**
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/pdf/pdf_reference.html

**This is the shortcut I meant:** http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/PDFToText.aspx

Comment: Thanks ondesertverge, but would you be able to prescribe the exact procedure? I'm not much familiar with PDF file format and stuff...

I tried pdftk to uncompress it, but it said it couldn't open the PDF file. I was actually doing all I could to sort the list, so didn't get much time to read the documentation. Will see it later. Thanks anyway. :)

Answer (score 0):

Well I sort of managed it. I first copied it to a plain text file, deleted all letters from it leaving only the serial number and corresponding marks, separated by spaces or tabs. Then using "import" in an OpenOffice Spreadsheet, told it the delimiters are spaces and tabs (combine them if necessary) and bingo! I got my rank.

But I would still like to know if it's possible to copy the whole table as it is. So keeping this question open.

Comment: Is this a one time deal or do want to build a tool to do this on a regular basis?

Comment: hi ninad, i am doing the same way like how you have explained above but the problem i am facing is when i am extracting a line which has only numbers, the position of the numbers are getting shuffled!! and for each pdf file i process, the position of this number is changing randomly,